# How to get the file/resource path for a QIcon

Tags: c++, qt, qicon

So let's say I do something like this:

```
QIcon myIcon(":/resources/icon.ico");
```

How can I later determine the path for that icon, e.g.

```
QString path = myIcon.getPath();
```

The problem is, there is no `getPath()` member, and I can't find anything similar, but surely there must be a way!

I guess I could inherit the `QIcon` class and add this functionality, but it's probably built in and I'm overlooking it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The filename isn't stored in [QIcon](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.5/src/gui/image/qicon.h#line60), it's only used for [constructing](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.5/src/gui/image/qicon.cpp#line602) the image.