# QT - How to get QPushButton Active On/Off Icon Name

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qpushbutton, qicon

I would specifically like to get the active on/off name of the icon for the qPushButton. I tried to log first the icon name like on my code but the output was always empty even if I tried to programmatically make an icon, any idea how to solve this?

Here's my code for just trying to log the icon name:

> qDebug() << "icon name " <<  ui->btnWestern1_2->icon().name(); //output: empty string

Just to verify my objective is to get the active on/off name not just the icon name but nothing works for me.

I'm using  Qt 5.2.1

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. the icon [`name`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qicon.html#name) method is not useful in your case.

The icon is created with a filename but the filename is not stored anywhere. 
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685903/2743307)

You can check the way your button is created by looking at the `uic` `ui_XXX.h` file.

If you want to do it progmatically you can a `property` to the button containing the two icons (on/off)?

Here is a (not tested) hint:

```
QStringList icons = (QStringList() << "icon1.png" << "icon2.png");

QIcon my_icon;
my_icon.addFile(QStringLiteral(icons[0]), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
my_icon.addFile(QStringLiteral(icons[1]), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);

QPushButton btn = new QPushButton(my_icon);
btn->setProperty("icons",icons);

qDebug() << btn->property("icons");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but may I know when does "name" method can be useful or be functional?

Comment: looks like it is used in case of using a theme : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qicon.html#name